# unexpected behavior of unsigned variables when assigned negative values

Tags: c, printf, output, unsigned, signed

Here is a code snippet:

```
unsigned short a=-1;
unsigned char b=-1;
char c=-1;
unsigned int x=-1;
printf("%d %d %d %d",a,b,c,x);
```

Hhy the output is this:

```
65535 255 -1 -1
```

?

Can anybody please analyze this ?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Your compiler should've warned you about `%d`. `%d` expects type `int` but not all the arguments are of type int. Therefore, the complier will perform an implicit cast to int before printing

Comment: either c=255 or x=very large no, but not both -1 -1

Comment: @user2976610 printf with %d as format converts to int. an int is signed. Therefore c is -1 and x is -1. Check Dariusz answer

Comment: if it is so then a and b might have also been converted into int..right

Comment: @user2976610 Indeed. if you would like to avoid the conversion you need to use `%c` for char , but there's no way (you would have to work around it) to print short integers. Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf

Answer (score 6):

You are printing the values using `%d` which is for signed numbers. The value is "converted" to a signed number (it actually stays the same bitwise, but the first bit is interpreted differently).

As for unsigned char and short - they are also converted to 32 bit int, so the values fit in it.

Had you used `%lld` (and cast the value as `long long`, otherwise it could be unspecified behavior) even the last two numbers may get printed as unsigned.

Anyway, **use `%u` for unsigned numbers.**

### How does it work?

Bit value of 255 is `11111111`. If treated like an unsigned number, it will be 255. If treated as a signed number - it'll be -1 (the first bit usually determines sign).
When you pass the value to `%d` in printf, the value is converted to a 32 bit integer, which looks like this: `00000000000000000000000011111111`. Since the first bit is 0, the value is printed simply as 255. It works similarily for your `short`.

The situation is different for 32 bit integer. It is immediately assigned a `11111111111111111111111111111111` value, which stands for -1 in singed notation. And since you have used `%d` in your printf, it is interpreted as `-1`.

Comment: i want detailed explanation plzz

Comment: If you used `%lld` you'd also need to cast to `long long` or you'd get undefined behavior.

Comment: @user2976610 extended the answer

Comment: @interjay thx, added the info; won't it be unspecified behavior in C, instead of undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should not assign negative values to "unsigned" variables.  You are trying to play tricks on the compiler, and who knows what it will do.  Now, "char n = -1;" is OK because "n" can legitimently take on negative values and the compiler knows how to treat it.

Comment: you can't play tricks on the compiler! assigning -1 to an unsigned variable is just another way to assign the maximum value possible to the variable. -1 --> 0xffff --> (unsigned)65535=(2^16)-1